# boto3 and botocore are required for this module in jenkins pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, ansible, boto3, botocore

I am trying to run ansible playbook via jenkins groovy scripts but keep getting error: `boto3 is required`. I have already installed boto3:

```
pip list boto | grep boto
boto3                             1.20.3
botocore                          1.23.3
```

I have inventory as:

```
[localhost]
localhost ansible_connection=local ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python
```

Python:

```
which python
/usr/bin/python
```

pip:

```
 which pip
/home/john/.local/bin/pip
```

boto:

```
find $HOME/.local -name 'boto3' -type d/home/john/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3
```

versions:

```
pip --version
pip 21.3.1 from /home/john/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

python --version
Python 3.6.9
```

Ansible:

```
which ansible
/usr/bin/ansible
```

Playbook in sh file:

```
ansible-playbook -c local \
    -e ansible_python_interpreter=$(which python) \
    -i localhost, \
    -e env="'${ENV}'" \
    -e image="'${IMAGE_NAME}'" \
    -e version="'${BUILD_NUMBER}'" \
    infra/test.ansible.yaml
```

What else did I miss to configure?

Comment: What do you mean by jenkins sh? Are you creating a jenkins job? How do you trigger the execution?

Comment: @kgiannakakis I meant groovy script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after days of struggle fixed my problem using the steps below:

1. Created virtual environment for python, boto and ansible
2. Edit the ansible inventory file to point the interpreter to python instead of `/usr/bin/python`

   sudo pip install virtualenv
   sudo pip install boto botocore
   source ansible_vEnv/bin/activate

Set the following in ansible inventory:

```
[localhost]
localhost ansible_python_interpreter=python
```

4. Gave the playbook command as `ansible-playbook -c local dir/test.yaml`

Note: make sure you use `boto` in yaml file and not boto3:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name:
    pip:
      name: boto // here
      state: present
```

Pointing the interpreter to `python` will actually pickup the python from our isolated environment i.e. virtual environment we created in step 2.

Also, I did installed ansible as root using:

1. `sudo su -`
2. Uninstalled the existing ansible that was installed using `apt-get`
3. Installed ansible using `pip install ansible`
4. Set the path in Jenkins as `/usr/bin` for ansible plugin in global tool configuration